# Parse Xml File from file with Php Customized

Tags: php, xml

i had fallowing code to try parse whole xml. Somewhere i made mistake and i can not get correct List from xml file.
There are 40+ sections and each section has differents.
Example of Xml - 4k+ Lines

**XML**

```
<ItemList>
    <Section Index="0" Name="Swords">
<Item Index="0" Slot="0" SkillIndex="0" Name="Kris" />
<Item Index="1" Slot="4" SkillIndex="0" Name="Blade" />
++++
++++
+++
++
+

    </Section>
    <Section Index="1" Name="Axes">
    <Item Index="0" Slot="0" SkillIndex="0" Name="Small Axe" />
    <Item Index="1" Slot="1" SkillIndex="0" Name="Hand Axe" />
    ++++
    ++++
    ++
    ++
    +
    </Section>
    sections goes more...
    </ItemList>
```

** Php Code Fixed xml parse**  No i have problem to write in txt file.

```
  $grabUrl = "Item.xml";

$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open($grabUrl);
while ($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'Section')
     //$node = $xml->expand();
        echo $xml->getAttribute('Index').'  <br>';
           if ($xml->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'Item')
                 echo 'Type:'.$xml->getAttribute('Index').' Section Name :'.$xml->getAttribute('Name').'  <br>';


$data = '';
$LogFileLocation = __PATH_CACHE__."Tracker/".date('F_j_Y').".txt";
$db              = fopen($LogFileLocation,'at');    
$data           .= ''.$xml->getAttribute('Index').'\t'.$xml->getAttribute('Name').'\n';
$data           .=''.$xml->getAttribute('Index').'\t'.$xml->getAttribute('Name').'\n';
fwrite($db,''.$xml->getAttribute('Index').'\t'.$xml->getAttribute('Name').'\n';);
fclose($db);

}
```

**Output**

```
Index: Name :
Index: Name :
Index: Name :
Index:0 Name :Swords
Index: Name :
Index:0 Name :Kris
Index: Name :
Index:1 Name :Short Sword
Index: Name :
```

My question is how can i get output as below. Thanks for help in advance.

```
Section Index : 0 Name: Swords
Item Index:0 Name :Kris
Item Index:1 Name :Short Sword
end
Section Index : 1 Name: Axes
Item Index:0 Name :Small Axe
Item Index:1 Name :Hand Axe
++
end

go on...
```

**Edit**

Code corrected, now i can get what i want. The problem is i cant parse it to the txt file. Any advices to parse that xml result to txt?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your current code performs `echo` construction on every loop iteration. You should perform outputting within `if` operator condition as shown bellow:

```
 ...
    $xml->open($XmlFile);
    while ($xml->read()) {
        if ($xml->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'Item'){
            $node = $xml->expand();
            echo 'Index:'.$xml->getAttribute('Index').'  Name :'.$xml->getAttribute('Name').'<br>';
        }

    }
    ....
```